# How to read Jenkins console SVN output in the Maven MOJO

Tags: svn, jenkins, maven-3, hudson, maven-plugin

I have a Jenkins job which will first update code from SVN repository and then I need to work on the updated files from SVN in my Maven plugin.

So, How can I get the updated files list from Jenkins into my MOJO (extends org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractMojo) class?

I was think one way to do this is to read Jenkins console where, SVN log is printed and parse that console output and get the updated files list. But I think there will be some better way to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you elaborate more what exactly you are trying to do? Are we talking about incremental builds?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have a nightly build job in jenkins. The job is to first run SVN update and then run my customized maven plugin job. In my maven plugin (MOJO) I need to get the list of updated files from SVN.

Comment: I have understood that you have your own MOJO but what is the purposes of this MOJO ? On the other hand you can take a look at the [SCM component](http://maven.apache.org/scm/) ?

Comment: @khmarbaise Thanks for the comment. In MOJO I basically do compile of the files, which are custom program files. The compiler is in MOJO. So right now I am doing compiling of all files in the sandbox every night, but the requirement is to compile only the files which are changed. So, I need a list of files which are changed in SVN repository.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to record the state of the files and afterwards you need to check which files have changed. The problem here is: You will be called on say rev 3 and the next time you will be called with rev 7, but the update (picking up the changed / new files) has already being done by (for example) Jenkins and now you need to know which files have been changed/added? This can only being done by using some supplemental information which is stored in the target folder (for example fingerprints of the files) which is checked like the maven-compiler-plugin already does. Reading SVN brings you back to the same problem? Which was the state you have been called the first time?

You need to store the information about the last update...so store the revision number somewhere? The next time you will be called compare it with the stored and you can make a decision what to do...

Better is to do such things on a file base so you are independent of the SCM system...but it will not change the need to identify somehow which file has been changed...

May be a look at http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-shared-incremental/ might be worth...

Furthermore you need to implement a kind of impact analyzis which checks things like you change class A (lets say it in Java) but class A is used by class B so you need to compile class B not allways...there are special cases to consider...
What about influences of other informations like configurations (for example a pom file change)?